# How can I change the width of b-form-select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using `b-form-select`, but by default it uses 100% width. How can I reduce the width? I tried something like that but that doesn't work.

```
 <b-form-select v-model="xxx" :options="yyy" width: 50%></b-form-select>
```

Comment: Ordinarily you'd use the [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#form-grid) to manage size. I'm not sure how you'd implement that with Bootstrap-Vue.

Comment: Looks like B-V has its own layout api: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#comp-ref-b-form-row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply CSS using `style` or `class`.
Also, `width: 50%` isn't valid HTML, I assume you meant `width="50%"`, which wont work on a `<select>`

#### Styles

```html
<b-form-select style="width: 50%"></b-form-select>
```

#### Class

```html
<b-form-select class="w-50"></b-form-select>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-form-select style="width: 50%"></b-form-select>
  <hr />
  <b-form-select class="w-50"></b-form-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-Vue uses a 12-column layout system.  Use `<b-row>` and `<b-col>` with the `cols` attribute.  In this case, you want 6 cols, i.e. half of 12:

```
<b-row>
  <b-col cols="6">
    <b-form-select v-model="xxx" :options="yyy"></b-form-select>
  </b-col> 
</b-row>
```

Using `cols` allows for dynamic sizes based on screen width.  For example, if you wanted to take up the full width on mobile but half on every other screen size, you can do it:

```
<b-row>
  <b-col cols="12" sm="6">
    <b-form-select v-model="xxx" :options="yyy"></b-form-select>
  </b-col> 
</b-row>
```